# How to post data to a soap service in mule

Tags: http, soap, mule

I have  a requirement.
I have a xml file and after transformation I need to send the payload to a soap service.
I have been using http-request for rest. But now for soap service which component should I use to send data.
I hope http-outbound is deprecated now.
Any help with example is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used WSConsumer Component. I have read all the details from the property file And its working as intended

Answer (score 1):

You could use http Request as well for sending soap request, you could use the XML to post to the Soap web service.

Comment: Can you please provide me the configuration details? I donot know what to put for port,path etc. What I have is just the wsdl. If it can accept the address parameter , I am not quite sure

Comment: No. My flow stops after dispatching data to soap service and for receiving data its a jms

Answer (score 0):

You could either use Web Service Consumer or Http-request + CXF.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/consuming-web-services-with-cxf

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/web-service-consumer